# Debugger not stepping into different projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible for a web project built on .NET framework 4.0 step into a project built on .NET framework 2? If so, how would I set this up?

These 2 projects are in different solutions. When I do a "Go to definition" from the web project, it opens up the metadata. In debug mode, the debugger never "steps into" the method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stepping into the project is definitely a supported scenario.  The likely cause for not stepping into it is that you don't have symbols loaded in the project or you have Just My Code (JMC) enabled.

The JMC situation is the most likely.  Try disabling it and retrying your scenario

> Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> Just My Code

Comment: Just tried that. Unfortunately, it did'nt help. For what it's worth - I have the source code for both the projects.

Comment: @user102533, interesting.  Did you ensure the symbols were loaded for the other project?  You can check by looking at the DLL in the Modules window.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it was the PDB problem.